# Grouping sets in Hive not producing the same results as SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hive, hiveql

I have a SQL Server query that I'm trying to convert to Hive, but I'm not getting the expected results using grouping sets. The general goal is to be able to pull all the info needed to sub-total each value, for each field to generate the data needed to create a report in one pass. for some reason, HIVE returns Y for field2 no matter what, where as SQL Server only returns the Y once.

In SQL Server, the query looks like this:

```
select 
    f.field1, f.field2, f.field3, count(*) count 
from 
    (select
         case 
            when field1 > '' then 'Selected'
            else '' 
         end field1,
         field2, field3,
         row_number() over (partition by ds.field4, ds.field5, ds.field6 order by ds.keyfield asc) recid1
     from 
         #data
     where 
         field3 in ('12345', '67890')
         and field2 = 'Y'
         and field1 > '') f 
where 
    recid1 = 1
group by 
    grouping sets ((),f.field1, f.field2, f.field3)
```

This returns these results:

```
field1  |field2|field3|count
NULL    |NULL  |12345 |10
NULL    |NULL  |67890 |2
NULL    |NULL  |NULL  |12
NULL    |Y     |NULL  |12
Selected|NULL  |NULL  |12
```

When I try to run a similar query in HIVE I get different results:

```
select f.field1, f.field2, f.field3,count(*) count 
from ( 
    select 
        case 
            when field1 > '' then 'Selected' 
            else '' 
        end field1,
        field2,
        field3,
        row_number() over (partition by ds.field4, ds.field5, ds.field6 order by ds.keyfield asc) recid1 
    from mydb.mytable ds 
where
    field3 in ('12345','67890')
    and ds.field2 = 'Y'
    and ds.field1 > '' 
)f where recid1=1
group by f.field1, f.field2, f.field3 
grouping sets ((),f.field1, f.field2, f.field3)
```

results:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| f.field1  | f.field2  | f.field3  | count  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| NULL      | Y         | 12345     | 10     |
| Selected  | Y         | NULL      | 12     |
| NULL      | Y         | NULL      | 12     |
| NULL      | Y         | 67890     | 2      |
| NULL      | Y         | NULL      | 12     |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

Sample data:

```
create table #data (field1 varchar(10),field2 varchar(10),field3 varchar(10),field4 varchar(10),field5 varchar(10),field6 varchar(10),keyfield varchar(10))
insert into #data select '1','Y','12345','1','1','1','1'
insert into #data select '2','Y','67890','2','2','2','2'
insert into #data select '3','Y','67890','3','3','3','3'
insert into #data select '4','Y','12345','4','4','4','4'
insert into #data select '5','Y','12345','5','5','5','5'
insert into #data select '6','Y','12345','6','6','6','6'
insert into #data select '7','Y','12345','7','7','7','7'
insert into #data select '8','Y','12345','8','8','8','8'
insert into #data select '9','Y','12345','9','9','9','9'
insert into #data select '10','Y','12345','10','10','10','10'
insert into #data select '11','Y','12345','11','11','11','11'
insert into #data select '12','Y','12345','12','12','12','12'
```

Comment: `grouping sets ((),(f.field1, f.field2, f.field3))` - Additional brackets?

Comment: sorry, having a hard time getting the formatting to work.

`|f.field1|f.field2|f.field3|count  |`
`|NULL    |Y       | NULL   |464237 |`
`|Selected|Y       | 04013  |455862 |`
`|Selected|Y       | 04007  |8375   |`
atleast in this case, i now got the field2 with other nulls. so progress, but not even close to sql server yet.

Comment: Can you provide your sample data for table?

Comment: added sample data to the original post

Comment: no love? anyone got any feedback?